# From any UTF-16 offset, find the corresponding String.Index that lies on a Character boundary

Tags: swift, string, unicode, swift4

**My goal:** given an arbitrary UTF-16 position in a `String`, find the corresponding `String.Index` that represents the `Character` (i.e. the extended grapheme cluster) the specified UTF-16 code unit is a part of.

**Example:**

[(I put the code in a Gist for easy copying and pasting.)](https://gist.github.com/ole/1065640c31d675d651964d502b1365db)

This is my test string:

```
let str = "‍"
```

(Note: to see the string as a single character, you need to read this on a reasonably recent OS/browser combination that can handle the new profession emoji with skin tones introduced in Unicode 9.)

It's a single `Character` (grapheme cluster) that consists of four Unicode scalars or 7 UTF-16 code units:

```
print(str.unicodeScalars.map { "0x\(String($0.value, radix: 16))" })
// → ["0x1f468", "0x1f3fe", "0x200d", "0x1f692"]
print(str.utf16.map { "0x\(String($0, radix: 16))" })
// → ["0xd83d", "0xdc68", "0xd83c", "0xdffe", "0x200d", "0xd83d", "0xde92"]
print(str.utf16.count)
// → 7
```

Given an arbitrary UTF-16 offset (say, 2), I can create a corresponding `String.Index`:

```
let utf16Offset = 2
let utf16Index = String.Index(encodedOffset: utf16Offset)
```

I can subscript the string with this index, but if the index doesn't fall on a `Character` boundary, the `Character` returned by the subscript might not cover the entire grapheme cluster:

```
let char = str[utf16Index]
print(char)
// → ‍
print(char.unicodeScalars.map { "0x\(String($0.value, radix: 16))" })
// → ["0x1f3fe", "0x200d", "0x1f692"]
```

Or the subscript operation might even trap (I'm not sure this is intended behavior):

```
let trappingIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: 1)
str[trappingIndex]
// fatal error: Can't form a Character from a String containing more than one extended grapheme cluster
```

You can test if an index falls on a `Character` boundary:

```
extension String.Index {
    func isOnCharacterBoundary(in str: String) -> Bool {
        return String.Index(self, within: str) != nil
    }
}

trappingIndex.isOnCharacterBoundary(in: str)
// → false (as expected)
utf16Index.isOnCharacterBoundary(in: str)
// → true (WTF!)
```

**The Issue:**

**I think the problem is that this last expression returns `true`.** [The documentation for `String.Index.init(_:within:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.index/2922833-init) says:

> If the index passed as `sourcePosition` represents *the start of an extended grapheme cluster*—the element type of a string—then the initializer succeeds.

Here, `utf16Index` doesn't represent the start of an extended grapheme cluster — the grapheme cluster starts at offset 0, not offset 2. Yet the initializer succeeds.

As a result, all my attempts to find the start of the grapheme cluster by repeatedly decrementing the index's `encodedOffset` and testing `isOnCharacterBoundary` fail.

Am I overlooking something? Is there another way to test if an index falls on the start of a `Character`? Is this a bug in Swift?

My environment: Swift 4.0/Xcode 9.0 on macOS 10.13.

*Update: Check out the interesting [Twitter thread about this question](https://twitter.com/olebegemann/status/912332606062174209).*

*Update: I reported the behavior of `String.Index.init?(_:within:)` in Swift 4.0 as a bug: [SR-5992](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5992).*

Comment: It seems that `String.Index(_:within:)` does not treat Emoji sequences as a single grapheme cluster (even if Swift 4 is based on Unicode 9).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution, using the [`rangeOfComposedCharacterSequence(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923407-rangeofcomposedcharactersequence)
method:

```
extension String {
    func index(utf16Offset: Int) -> String.Index? {
        guard utf16Offset >= 0 && utf16Offset < utf16.count else { return nil }
        let idx = String.Index(encodedOffset: utf16Offset)
        let range = rangeOfComposedCharacterSequence(at: idx)
        return range.lowerBound
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let str = "a‍bcd‍‍‍e"
for utf16Offset in 0..<str.utf16.count {
    if let idx = str.index(utf16Offset: utf16Offset) {
        print(utf16Offset, str[idx])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 a
1 ‍
2 ‍
3 ‍
4 ‍
5 ‍
6 ‍
7 ‍
8 b
9 
10 
11 
12 
13 c
14 
15 
16 d
17 ‍‍‍
18 ‍‍‍
19 ‍‍‍
20 ‍‍‍
21 ‍‍‍
22 ‍‍‍
23 ‍‍‍
24 ‍‍‍
25 ‍‍‍
26 ‍‍‍
27 ‍‍‍
28 e
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very nice solution that I did not think of. It even seem to work with indices from the UTF-8 view, so it's not limited to UTF-16 offset.s

Answer (score 1):

This has been [fixed in Swift 4.1](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5992).