# Get range from unicode character symbols. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, range, nsrange

I use `textView(_: shouldChangeTextIn: replacementText:)` function to change the input data depending on the situation. I use range, but I can not get the Swift Range when using unicode character symbols (eg **( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)** ). Please, tell me how it can be done?

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        let maxLenthNotReached = textView.text.count + (text.count - range.length) <= maxTextLength

        if maxLenthNotReached {
            guard let newRange = Range(range, in: identityString) else { return false }
            identityString = identityString.replacingCharacters(in: newRange, with: text)
        }

        return maxLenthNotReached
    }
```

[Example project](https://github.com/alexanderkhitev/TestTextView)

An app crash example http://take.ms/ojIJq

**Update**: I changed this method but I got a crash again when deleting

```
"entering data" ""
"testString" "༼ つ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° ༽つ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡"
"entering data" ""

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    debugPrint("textView.text", textView.text)
    testString = textView.text.replacingCharacters(in: Range(range, in: textView.text)!, with: text)//
    debugPrint("testString", testString)
    return true
}
```

**Update 1**: I entered these characters in the textView

```
( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)༼ つ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° ༽つ
```

Then I started to delete the characters with the right to the left after the three right few symbols were deleted `° ༽つ`, and the  car emoji has left, then I can not get the range, since I put the guard and application doesn't crash, if I remove that of course there will be app crash.

Full code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet private weak var textView: UITextView! {
        didSet {
            textView.delegate = self
            textView.text = "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)༼ つ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° ༽つ"
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Properties

    private var testString = ""

}


extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        guard let newRange = Range(range, in: textView.text) else {
            return false
        }
        testString = textView.text.replacingCharacters(in: newRange, with: text)
        return true
    }

}
```

**Update 2**: After talking with Martin, I found and provided one detail that this problem only happens with the Google keyboard, and with the default keyboard everything works as expected.

The original line I had was `"( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)༼ つ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° ༽つ”`, this line is used for an example.If I start deleting this line from left to right, I get the app crash, Martin asked to show the latest data in the console before the app crashes, last print before crash is `textView" "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)༼ つ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡" "range" {27, 1}`

Comment: A *self-contained* reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: You should search the range in textView.text, not in identityString.

Comment: @MartinR I updated my post. I'm searching in textView.text, but I still get the app crash

Comment: Can you make it  a *self-contained* example that does not require downloading a project and some UI interaction? Something like let textViewText = "...", let replacementText = "...", let range = ... , ...

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I ran your code with `let newRange = Range(range, in: textView.text)!` and the given initial string, and could delete all characters from the right, without crashing.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, sorry, please, one more detail. I delete using the Google keyboard, but it does not work with it as expected. Once again I'm sorry. Here is the result with google keyboard, but when I switch to default keyboard, everything works as expected. http://take.ms/1NnPU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172695/discussion-between-martin-r-and-alexander).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion:

- OP is using the Google keyboard,
- the text view delegate method is called with

  ```
  textView.text = "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)༼ つ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡"
  range = { 27, 1 }
  ```
- and then

  ```
  let newRange = Range(range, in: textView.text)
  ```

  returns `nil`.

The reason is that the range points into the “middle” of the  character,
which is stored as a UTF-16 surrogate pair. Here is a simplified self-contained
example:

```
let text = "Hello !"
let range = NSRange(location: 7, length: 1)
let newRange = Range(range, in: text)
print(newRange as Any) // nil
```

This looks like a bug (in the Google keyboard?) to me, but there is a possible workaround.

The “trick” is to determine the closest surrounding range of “composed
character sequences,” and here is how that can be done
(compare [From any UTF-16 offset, find the corresponding String.Index that lies on a Character boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408487/from-any-utf-16-offset-find-the-corresponding-string-index-that-lies-on-a-chara/46409761#46409761)):

```
extension String {
    func safeRange(from nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        guard nsRange.location >= 0 && nsRange.location <= utf16.count else { return nil }
        guard nsRange.length >= 0 && nsRange.location + nsRange.length <= utf16.count else { return nil }
        let from = String.Index(encodedOffset: nsRange.location)
        let to = String.Index(encodedOffset: nsRange.location + nsRange.length)
        return rangeOfComposedCharacterSequences(for: from..<to)
    }
}
```

Now

```
let newRange = textView.text.safeRange(from: range)
```

returns a `String` range that enclosed the entire  character. In our 
simplified example:

```
let text = "Hello !"
let range = NSRange(location: 7, length: 1)
let newRange = text.safeRange(from: range)
print(newRange as Any) // Optional(Range(...))   
print(text.replacingCharacters(in: newRange!, with: "")) // Hello !
```